# Shortcut for nested function call

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project where I often need to do things like:

```
map(lambda r: f(g(h(r))), mylist)
```

Currently I've created this class:

```
class NestedCalls(object):
    def __init__ (self, *args):
        self.__fn = list(args)
        self.__fn.reverse()
    def __call__ (self, *args, **kargs):
        v = self.__fn[0] (*args, **kargs)
        for f in self.__fn[1:]:
            v = f (v)
        return v
```

Then I simply do:

```
map(NetstedCalls(f, g, h), mylist)
```

Which works pretty well, but I wonder if there was a built-in tool to do the same things? I've been looking through python docs but unfortunately I don't really how to name such a tool / class.

Comment: Hint: this is called function composition. I'd call the class `compose`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate functional way to do stuff . Actually went and build simple functions to illustrate it :

```
def plus1(a):
    return a+1
def minus3(a):
    return a-3
def or5(a):
    return a*5

# this one could be skipped
def apply(a,b):
    return b(a)

reduce(apply,[plus1,or5,minus3],10)
# without apply
reduce(lambda a,b: b(a),[plus1,or5,minus3],10)
```

Is this what you were looking for?